# need help to load yolov5

Tags: model, yolov5

trying load yolov5:

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', classes=30)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetection/best.pt   ')['model'].state_dict())

model = model.fuse().autoshape()
```

out:

```
runfile('/Users/lebedev/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetection/loadingmodel.py', wdir='/Users/lebedev/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetection')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in do_open
...skipped...

ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lebedev/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetection/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3378, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-21519fa4e2b1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/lebedev/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetection/loadingmodel.py', wdir='/Users/lebedev/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetection')
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/lebedev/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetection/loadingmodel.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', classes=30)
  File "/Users/lebedev/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetection/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 537, in load
    repo_or_dir = _get_cache_or_reload(repo_or_dir, force_reload, trust_repo, "load",
  File "/Users/lebedev/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetection/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 180, in _get_cache_or_reload
    repo_owner, repo_name, ref = _parse_repo_info(github)
  File "/Users/lebedev/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetection/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 133, in _parse_repo_info
    with urlopen(f"https://github.com/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/tree/main/"):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)>
```

WTF: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)> ???

I need use it for local OpenCV, Colab have no access to my webcam =7

Answer (score 0):

```
    import torch 
    model = torch.hub.load('Ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom',
                            model_path, force_reload=True,
                            trust_repo=True)
    results = model(image_path)
    df = results.pandas().xyxy[0]
    print(df.head())  # you can extract predicted bboxes coords from df
```